# How to make adaptive-wrap play with text-scale-mode?

Tags: emacs, indentation, word-wrap

I recently found out about `adaptive-wrap.el`, which works very well with unscaled text. But as I often use Emacs (24.3) in `text-scale-mode`, I have noticed that the wrap prefix does not scale with the remainder of the text.

[image]

As you can see, the second and third lines are only indented by the width of the unscaled prefix. How do I change `adaptive-wrap.el` to account for different text scales?

This might seem like the pettiest of requests, but I may as well try and remove a tiny bit of unexpected behaviour.

[adaptive-wrap.el](https://github.com/emacsmirror/adaptive-wrap/blob/master/adaptive-wrap.el)

Comment: Perhaps you could consider e-mailing the authors, who are listed near the top of the file.  The file is only a few lines of code (suggesting there are not so many options for user customization), so a solution may need to be written into the code.